# how to declare a char*[20][250]

Tags: c

i have a char * [][] and i need to empty it, and make a new one every now and then, but i dont know how to reinitialize it over and over again

i tried

```
args = malloc(sizeof(char*[20][250])*20);
```

and

```
args = malloc(sizeof(char***)*20);
```

but i still cant reinitilize the array. Is the array really 20 X 250 with a char* as the element perhaps?

and how do you iterate through a char array that is of the type *[20][250]?

this is for the execv and will be used like this

```
for(int i =0 ;i< maxArgs;i++){
    execv(args[i][0],args[i]);
    ERROR("failed to start");
}
```

Comment: Downvoted, because question doesn't contain [mcve]. As I result, no one knows exactly what you are trying to do, and answers try to guess what your intended data type is.

Comment: it is very clear in the title that my data type is char * [][] more specifically char * [20][250]. i want to initialize it, and then re-initialize it. and it doesnt have an example because it have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Pointers are traditionally hard for beginners. It's unclear whether you have understood what you want. You can see from answers that they have different ideas on what you need to do. Good question would have a short example of using tha variable after the allocation to demonstrate what you actually need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `args` is declared as:

```
char* args[20][250];
```

You can allocate memory for each item of that array using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
{
   for ( int j = 0; j < 250; ++j )
   {
      args[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(*args[i][j])*(SIZE_OF_STRING+1));
   }
}
```

If `args` is declared as:

```
char*** args;
```

You need a few more `malloc` calls.

**Step 1**

Allocate memory for `arg`.

```
args = malloc(sizeof(*args)*20);
```

**Step 2**

Allocate memory for `args[0] - args[19]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
{
   args[i] = malloc(sizeof(*args[i])*250);
}
```

**Step 3**

Allocate memory for `args[0][0] - args[19][249]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
{
   for ( int j = 0; j < 250; ++j )
   {
      args[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(*args[i][j])*(SIZE_OF_STRING+1));
   }
}
```

**Combine them**

```
args = malloc(sizeof(*args)*20);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
{
   args[i] = malloc(sizeof(*args[i])*250);
   for ( int j = 0; j < 250; ++j )
   {
      args[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(*args[i][j])*(SIZE_OF_STRING+1));
   }
}
```

Comment: SIZE_OF_STRING + 1 assuming it's containing a regular c string.

Answer (score 4):

Postfix operators are always higher precedence than prefix, so when you say

```
char*[20][250]
```

you get an array of 20 arrays of 250 pointers to characters.  You can use parentheses the bind the `*` more tightly:

```
char (*)[20][250]
```

denotes a pointer to an array of 20 arrays of 250 chars.  So if you have

```
char (*args)[20][250];
```

you can use

```
args = malloc(sizeof(char [20][250]));
```

Comment: Interesting style: `malloc(sizeof(char [20][250]))`

Comment: @chux That's the form that you'd use if you wanted the allocated memory to be in the form of a 20×250 2D array of single-`char`s, as Chris says with _“denotes a pointer to an array of 20 arrays of 250 chars”_.  If you instead wanted a 20×250 2D array of C-strings, I don't believe a single `malloc()` will work.

Comment: @chux: I prefer `malloc(sizeof *args)`, but I don't think that's what you're talking about. However, the onky text application I can think of which might fit that datatype would be a terminal emulator/editor/screen thingy, and even there unicode has changed most of the old certainties.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson: a "C string" is not a type it's a (somewhat vague) concept -- a null-terminated sequence of chars.  A `char [20][250]` is a type, one that can hold 20 "C strings" each of which is up to 249 characters.  Depending on exactly what the OP wants, all of this may or may not be relevant...

Comment: @ChrisDodd  Correct, a “C string” is not a type, but it is a highly specific concept with a ubiquitously-agreed upon type (`char *`) and memory layout (zero-terminated array).  Similarly, a “wide C string” is always `wchar_t *` and zero-term; and a “Pascal string” is always `char *` with the first byte containing the length (and usually zero-term).  I dare you to find any book or platform documentation from the last 30 years that disagrees with this ubiquitous agreement (if not standard).  |  Yes, what the OP wants is vague, as @user694733 noted.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson: a "C string" often refers to a char array type not a char pointer type. K&R use the term this way, as does pretty much every book ever published.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Yes, that's why I wrote _“memory layout (zero-terminated **array**)”_.  Also, in C, arrays are implemented using pointers— all arrays are of pointer type.  I'm failing to see how your distinction of K&R using the `char[]` syntax over the `char *` syntax (both of which are the same type) disproves anything I've said or supports your claim that _“a "C string" is a somewhat vague concept”_.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson: Arrays are *NOT* pointer types -- that misconception is behind most new user confusion with C.  Yes, arrays can be implicitly converted to pointers, but the distinction *IS* important, as this and other questions show.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Disagree.  The type of data is format, layout, and usage patterns of it.  Because of this, the `char *` type is not of `char[]` type, but the `char[]` is certainly of `char *` type.  Although `char *` is more generalized and less specific than `char[]`, it is still the same type.  It sounds like you're extrapolating the imposed limits of type-checking to be the definition of a type— would you agree that `AString` defined as `typedef char[] AString;` is a distinct type from `char[]`?  I wouldn't, in a general context.

Comment: @ChrisDodd It's also worth noting that a C string cannot be dynamically alloced into a `char[]`— only a `char *` will work.  It is for this reason that I used that syntax in my answer & comments.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, when you desire a 2D array of type `char*[20][250]`, what you're asking for in C-speak is a 20-element array of `char*[250]`s, each of which is a 250-element array of `char *` C-strings *(each of which is an array of `char`s)*.

Because a dynamically-allocated 2D array isn't a single area of memory but rather an array of pointers to other arrays, you can't do this in one step<sup>1</sup>.  The allocation that will do what you want would look like this:

```
char ***args;

args = malloc(sizeof(char**[20]));
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    args[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*[250]));

    // optional, depending on your usage:
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
        args[i][j] = ""; // This makes every `char *` element point to the same location in memory— the location of the compiled-in `""` / `(char *){ '\0' }`.
}
```

To free the memory, structure your calls the same as the `malloc`-ing code, but in reverse-hierarchical order:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    free(args[i]);
free(args);
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Okay, so it is technically possible to allocate it as one big blob and then wire up the 20-element array to point into the desired offsets into the blob.  This convolutes `free()`ing though and usually isn't necessary— for most use-cases, the performance gains would be negligible (and you'd still need to `malloc()` a separate array of pointers that address into the 2D blob).  You typically only see 2D-blob allocation when data is massively 2D — such as image data — and `data[x][y]` access syntax is eschewed in favor of `data[y * width + x]` syntax because it's no less efficient than what the compiler would do, and doesn't require more than one `malloc`/`free` pair per blob of data.</sub>

Comment: So, if I declare `int a[20][250]`, you're telling me that it is not one contiguous block of memory?

Comment: @pat Just added a footnote about exactly that.  You're correct, it is not.  C doesn't have true 2-dimensional array support; it only has array-of-pointers-to-anything-else support.

Comment: Declare `a` as above, and print `sizeof(a)`.  You will find it to be `20*250*sizeof(int)`.  Not a pointer to be found here.

Comment: @pat: Oh sorry, I misread your comment— I thought you were asking about malloc'ing `int [20][250]`, not letting the compiler stack-allocation-lay-it-out.  Yes, you're right about that.  I forget how stack-allocation arrays work exactly.  If you can answer the question using that kind of layout with malloc, go for it!!  But IIRC, memory layout done at compile time gets to make some shortcuts you don't have available at `malloc()`-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a typedef for a 2d array like so:

```
    typedef char *array2d_t[20][250];
```

You can now `malloc` enough memory to hold a single instance of this 2d array:

```
    array2d_t *array3d = malloc(1 * sizeof(*array3d));
```

Because pointers behave like arrays of the things to which they point, we actually have a 3d array whose first dimension has arity 1 (note the `1 *` in the malloc), so the first index can be only 0.  We can index it thus:

```
    array3d[0][0][0] = "Hello";
    array3d[0][1][0] = "World";
    array3d[0][19][249] = "End of the world!";
```

Or, if you prefer, we can dereference the pointer explicitly:

```
    (*array3d)[0][0] = "Hello";
    (*array3d)[1][0] = "World";
    (*array3d)[19][249] = "End of the world!";
```

Alternatively, we can declare a typedef for a 1d array like so:

```
    typedef char *array1d_t[250];
```

An can now `malloc` enough memory to hold 20 instances of this 1d array:

```
    array1d_t *array2d = malloc(20 * sizeof(*array2d));
```

We no can now index the array with:

```
    array2d[0][0] = "Hello";
    array2d[1][0] = "World";
    array2d[19][249] = "End of the world!";
```

Comment: Typedefs… I didn't think that would work so +1.  This does still limit the array to a size determined at compile-time, but that's out-of-scope from what the OP's asking.

Comment: Typedefs are not necessary, but they make things simpler to understand.  The number of dimensions must be fixed, and all dimensions except the first must be constant in order for the compiler to do the address computation.  If you are willing to write the address computation by hand, you can have a dynamic number of dynamically sized dimensions, and still have all of the elements remain contiguous.